# When inserting timestamp to a table it inserts as date - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have `table1` with data on it and in every row there is `"period_start"` and `"period_end"`, both columns are `dates`. Ex: '2021-06-30'.

I have a `table2` I created with 2 columns of the same name, this time they are saved as `timestamp` (client wants as timestamp).

I ran a query that inserts the results of `table1` to `table2` but converts the date columns to timestamp. For some reason I couldn't understand, the results in `table2` are all dates and not as timestamp.

Creating `table2` (removed other columns):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2
(
    ,period_start timestamp   ENCODE zstd
    ,period_end timestamp   ENCODE zstd
)
```

Inserting from `table1`:

```
insert into table2 (period_start ,period_end)
select 
    cast(to_date(period_start,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp), 
    cast(DATEADD(millisecond, -1,last_day(period_start + 75) + 1) as timestamp)
from table1;
```

When running the same select I see the results as timestamp perfectly, when querying from `table2` the results are saved as date.

Comment: I'd double check your assumptions and make a simple test case.  It is highly likely that you have an error in what you are doing as it is near impossible that RS is getting something this basic wrong.  One possibility - "create table if not exist" will do nothing if the table already exists.  Are you sure that the table is defined with these columns as being timestamps?

Comment: Yes I dropped "table2" before creating it as written above.

Comment: I see no mention of dropping table2 above.  Either way I expect that in order to get help with this you will need to post a test case that demonstrates the issue in question.  What are the steps that anyone can use to recreate this issue?  My bet is that in putting this test case together you will find the mistake.

Comment: I worded it poorly. My bad!

Comment: I meant - I dropped table2 before creating it, I created it as written above.

I will try your suggestion Bill. Thank you.

Comment: Turns out the quries are indeed fine (I'm glad). It was a problem with DBeaver that for some reason didn't show them as timestamp. I had to exit and enter the program and then it worked. Thanks again Bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the queries are indeed fine (I'm glad). It was a problem with DBeaver that for some reason didn't show them as timestamp. I had to exit and enter the program and then it worked.